# Angular 6 how to wait for httpclient to return

Tags: angular, httpclient, angular6

I am trying to call a function on my flask interface from Angular 6. A function that should verify some credentials upon a click and according to the response either show an error or navigate to a page.

Thought I can not seem to be able to find a way to wait for the response before executing the next line of code. This causes a bug where the button needs to be pressed twice for the navigation to happen.

I tried using `asyc/await`, tried using `.then`, tried switching the `subscribe` to `map` but nothing works.

I guess I am missing something critical.

```
onClick() {
    let data = {
        // some data
    }
    let response = this.login(data);
    if (response["valid"] === true) {
        this.router.navigate(['/cool_page']);
    }
}

login(data) {
    let login_data = {}
    this.httpClient.post('http://somedomain.com/login', JSON.stringify(data)).subscribe( response => {
        login_data = response;    
    });

    return login_data; //this remains empty
}
```

Comment: `HttpClient.post` returns an `Observable`. Please refer to the [official guide](https://angular.io/guide/http).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an Observable/http/async call in angular2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43055706/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-observable-http-async-call-in-angular2)

Comment: The `login` method should return the Observable. You then subscribe to it in `onClick` and do all the processing inside of the callback.

Answer (score 3):

It require small correction related to Subscription.

```
onClick() {
    let data = {
        // some data
    }
     let response = this.login(data).subscribe( response => {
        if (response["valid"] === true) {
        this.router.navigate(['/cool_page']);
      }
    });

}

login(data) {
    let login_data = {}
    return this.httpClient.post('http://somedomain.com/login', JSON.stringify(data));
}
```

Comment: is there a way to  do it without using a callback?

Comment: Thats how asynchronous call works. What is the issue you see with callback ?

Comment: @Steinfeild You could call `toPromise()` on the returning Observable and then use `async`/`await`. But I would suggest working with Observables as most Angular code is based around it.